# Runtime Error 13 Type Mismatch when passing a userform textbox value to a function

Tags: excel, vba, function, runtime-error, userform

I have a userform with textboxes, and some of those are supposed to contain integers. I found somewhere on the internet (I think on this site) this IsInteger function which I have stored in a module just for functions:

```
Function IsInteger()
If IsNumeric(testsubject) Then
    If testsubject - Int(testsubject) <> 0 Then
        integerYes = True
    Else: integerYes = False
    End If
End If
End Function
```

The following code block relates to one of the userform textboxes:

```
  Private Sub IB_LoanTermYears_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    'Data validation
        If Me.IB_LoanTermYears.Value = "" Then
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Me.IB_LoanTermYears.Value) = False Then
            blahAnswer = MsgBox("Please enter a valid number.", , "Invalid Entry")
            Me.IB_LoanTermYears.SetFocus
        ElseIf IsInteger(Me.IB_LoanTermYears.Value) = False Then
            blahAnswer = MsgBox("Please enter a whole number.", , "Invalid Entry")
            Me.IB_LoanTermYears.SetFocus
        ElseIf Me.IB_LoanTermYears.Value < 0 Then
            blahanswer MsgBox("Please enter a positive number.", , "Invalid Entry")
            Me.IB_LoanTermYears.SetFocus
        End If
    End Sub
```

When I exit the textbox, I get a runtime error 13 with `ElseIf IsInteger(Me.IB_LoanTermYears.Value) = False Then` highlighted. What gives? I saw a very similar post that concluded that other empty textboxes were messing things up, but I don't see how that can affect this textbox as they're not linked in any way except that they're in the same userform.

Thanks!

Comment: Two things: Your function `IsInteger` doesn't accept any arguments, but you're trying to pass it an argument. Also, that function doesn't *return* anything.

Comment: `testsubject - Int(testsubject) <> 0` - should be `=0`. Or change the `True` and `False` around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the Fuction accepts inputs and the output is Boolean.

Since the default of a Boolean is FALSE we only need to change to `True`

```
Function IsInteger(testsubject As Variant) As Boolean
If IsNumeric(testsubject) Then
    IsInteger = (testsubject - CInt(testsubject) = 0)
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because the function does not take arguments. This is a better way to use the Integer funciton, which would actually check, whether the parsed variant could be converted to `Long` without a loss. E.g.: `Clng(43.4)` would return `43`, thus a loss appears:

```
Function ParseToLong(testSubject As Variant) As Boolean

    If IsNumeric(testSubject) Then
        If testSubject - CLng(testSubject) = 0 Then
            ParseToInteger = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    ParseToInteger = False

End Function
```

Just keep in mind, that `ParseToLong("32")` would return `True`, as far as the string "32" could be converted to numeric `32`.